Visual Studio Code / function like in SSMS Query shortcut
How to configure VS code keybindings to run directly procedure under shortcut?
For ex. I highlight name of object in query and run procedure under shortcut.
Or maybe you know alternative soft which has this funtion.
In SSMS is really simple to config.
I tried to use some extensions for VS code, but nothing works exactly like that

I don't really understand what you're actually trying to ask here. Are you saying you want to create a custom shortcode in VSCode that runs a specific Stored Procedure on a specific server in a specific database?

@ThomA in ssms one can configure query shortcuts, when you select a text and press Ctrl-1 or whatever, it can run some code that accepts the selected text as parameter, very handy. Although, not sure why one would be using VS Code for sql =)

Ahh, no don't think there's anything like that in VSCode. Might be in ADS mind. SSMS is a specific tool for SQL Server, where as VSCode is not.

I checked that in keybindings there is possibility, but can't find extension which add executequery command

Azure Data Studio does have this feature.
